# Sorting JSON file elements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sorting, discord.js

I have a JSON file which looks like this:

```
{"players":[{"username":"name1","score":36},{"username":"name2","score":8},{"username":"name3","score":1},{"username":"name4","score":18}]}
```

I want to sort it out so it's in descending order by scores.
I tried with forEach and with .sort but I didn't succeed.

Comment: can you share your code please

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try by using lodash

```
_.orderBy(arr, ['username'], ['desc'])
```